# Carry text message in a button without displaying it in Android

Tags: android, ios, button, view

Carry text message in a Button without displaying it in Android
I don't want to use any extra variable to carry my data with the Button instead `setText` to the Button itself. I want the text on the button should not be visible or rather should be clear but the button should be made visible.

P.S: I already have setTag for the button or the view in use, so cant use that.

I have seen in iOS App development that one can setTitle for the button or a view and set their color to clear so that the content cant be seen.

What I have tried so far is this :

```
square.setText("-1");
square.setTextSize(0);
square.setTextColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); 
square.setTextColor(R.drawable.trans);
```

Here : "-1" is the data which would be changed to `0 & 1` depending on program logic, but this data should not be visible to user and I use these data by using getText() function.

(I dont want to set this button to invisible or gone, as this buttons are clickable )

Thank You in advance !

Comment: Sounds like a very odd thing to want. Could you post some code to show why this makes sense?

Comment: As I have got 100s of buttons with tag, I want this buttons to carry value along with them so that these values can be used in my programming logic. Hence have the clear text, that wont be visible but accompanies info along with it and at the same time the button intact right where I want them to be. :)

Comment: Fair enough, still just seems weird to me. I would never mix GUI and logic. What if you were to apply a new theme and have to remove the button?

Comment: why don't you set the tag of the button with the text you want?

Comment: all those buttons are dynamically made. So here my Logic and GUI need to go hand in hand. Thank You anyways, I know my description should have been much more clearer. Thanks for the concerns sir :)

Comment: @NSQuamber I already have this tags under use, To put some more light that would make the understanding for my project clearer I would say, I am developing Dots & Boxes game, where all the lines (Horizontal, vertical) have setTag which would help me while setting up logic for the game. And this setText thing would help me decide which player has played his/her turn and accordingly increment their score count. And this all layout is dynamically created so that it fits out neat on every Android device. Hope this made little sense. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set **Transparency** to the **text color of button** like this, Text will not be visible anymore

```
  <Button android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:text="Invisible button"
        android:textColor="#00000000"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this way..

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Comment: I guess its the same what I did at runtime & yeah, I had my background too set to transparent, which changes when I click on them. Thanks for making an attempt to provide me with a solution #Appreciated